# How to install older version(1.6.18) svn on MAC

Tags: macos, svn

The MAC provide the #1.7.10 SVN client, but my project is using #1.6.18 SVN.

So that I received the error message "Working copy is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)"

Current I CANNOT upgrade my project svn version. So I think the only way for me is re-install the older version SVN. (please kindly advise me if there is better solution)

And my questions are:

1. Can I use the #1.7 SVN client on #1.6 SVN working copy? IF NO
2. How can I uninstall older SVN and re-install older version SVN?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 1.7 client can work on a 1.6 WC **after** you execute `svn upgrade`. After that event, 1.6 clients will not be able to use that working copy.

You can install another version of SVN to a non-default path, and either put that path earlier in your `$PATH` environment variable, or specify the full path to the binary each time you use it (if you go this route, you can create an `alias` in your shell to simplify it, but be careful as you might get confused as to which svn is which)

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem using version 1.7.10 even if your server is 1.6.8. What you shouldn't do is *share* working copies between systems. There is no guarantee that one Subversion client will use the same working copy format as another. For example, some Windows clients use `_svn` directories instead of `.svn` directories -- especially for VisualStudio development.

For the longest time, most clients used the default Subversion client format that has pretty much remained unchanged until the 1.7 client. In that client, the `.svn` folders found in each directory were removed to have just a single `.svn` folder in the root of the directory. This makes the 1.7 command line client working copy incompatible with the earlier formats.

You never explained how your Mac has a 1.6.8 working copy on it. Is it that you have some sort of GUI client on your Mac that is using the older format, or do you have a *share* that you use on two different systems. If you're doing the latter, don't. Check out a separate working copy on each system.

If you need to *share* changes between working copy without doing a commit, use the `svn diff` command to create a *patch file*. Then use [svn patch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html) to apply this *patch file* to the other working copy.

Answer (score 0):

Install the older version in a location on your path that is either higher than the default implementation.

i.e. svn is installed in /usr/bin/ by default (as I can see on my system) but usr/local/bin is higher in my PATH, so if I were to do this I would install the older version in usr/local/bin

Comment: Sorry, where can I download the 1.6.18 SVN for mac command? I cannot fine the related file on below URL: 
http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Please kindly advise me if anything is incorrect.

Comment: You can get it from the apache distribution archive http://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/

Comment: Hi, I had copied SVN (1.6.18) binary file into path "usr/local/bin". But when I use "svn" alias, it still link to path "usr/bin/svn".

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. You can rollback from 1.7 (should work on Mavericks) to 1.6.

#### Save your existing 1.7 install to another folder

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/svn* ~/Documents/svn_1.7
```

#### Install XCode and symlink the 1.6 version from there

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin/svn /usr/bin/svn
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin/svnadmin /usr/bin/svnadmin
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin/svndumpfilter /usr/bin/svndumpfilter
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin/svnlook /usr/bin/svnlook
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin/svnserve /usr/bin/svnserve
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin/svnsync /usr/bin/svnsync
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/subversion-1.6/bin/svnversion /usr/bin/svnversion
```

Voila!

Comment: Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) includes svn version 1.7.20 (r1667490) compiled Aug 17 2015, 15:24:52